# Return from inside a function defined inside another function in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I know that the title isn't very clear, so I'll try to explain in more depth:

I have a function f defined inside a function g, and I want to be able to call f from inside g, and make f make g return something.  For example:

```
def g():
    def f():
        return(True) # I want g to return this value when f is called
    f() # I cannot replace this with return(f()) because the context of this problem is extremely weird.
```

Because people have requested the context:

```
class Color:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

def requestColor(default=Color(0, 0, 0)):

    colorGUI = tk.Tk()
    colorGUI.title('Select Color')

    rLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='R: ', anchor=tk.E)
    gLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='G: ', anchor=tk.E)
    bLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='B: ', anchor=tk.E)

    rEntry = Entry(colorGUI)
    gEntry = Entry(colorGUI)
    bEntry = Entry(colorGUI)

    # this is one method that I want to have the return statement in
    def saveCommand():
        colorGui.destroy()
        return(Color(int(rEntry.get()), int(gEntry.get()), int(bEntry.get())))

    # this is another method that I want to have the return statement in
    def quitCommand():
        colorGui.destroy()
        return(Color(default.r, default.g, default.b))

    # I want to return the color when one of these buttons is pushed.
    saveButton = Button(colorGUI, text='SAVE', command=saveCommand)
    quitButton = Button(colorGUI, text='CANCEL'command=quitCommand)

    rEntry.insert(0, default.r)
    gEntry.insert(0, default.g)
    bEntry.insert(0, default.b)

    rLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    rEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    gLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    gEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    bLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    bEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    quitButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
    saveButton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
```

I made this method becasue I want to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
newColor = requestColor(oldColor)
```

in several places in my program.

Comment: well if you cannot change `f()` to `return f()`, then what exactly can you change? what are the feasible code changes?

Comment: Some more context would probably be helpful, if you can't just return f(). Please post the minimum amount of code required to understand the problem.

Comment: You were right the first time: *"I know that the title isn't very clear"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to make the button commands modify an existing  `Color`, rather than trying to return a new `Color`.

Here is a working demo based on your example code that does that:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Color:
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

def requestColor(default=Color(0, 0, 0)):

    # this will be modified later by the save command
    result = Color(default.r, default.g, default.b)

    colorGUI = tk.Tk()
    colorGUI.title('Select Color')

    rLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='R: ', anchor=tk.E)
    gLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='G: ', anchor=tk.E)
    bLabel = Label(colorGUI, text='B: ', anchor=tk.E)

    rEntry = Entry(colorGUI)
    gEntry = Entry(colorGUI)
    bEntry = Entry(colorGUI)

    def saveCommand():
        # set the new values
        result.r = int(rEntry.get())
        result.g = int(gEntry.get())
        result.b = int(bEntry.get())
        colorGUI.destroy()

    def quitCommand():
        # keep the default values
        colorGUI.destroy()

    saveButton = Button(colorGUI, text='SAVE', command=saveCommand)
    quitButton = Button(colorGUI, text='CANCEL', command=quitCommand)

    rEntry.insert(0, default.r)
    gEntry.insert(0, default.g)
    bEntry.insert(0, default.b)

    rLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    rEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    gLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    gEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
    bLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    bEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
    quitButton.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)
    saveButton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

    colorGUI.mainloop()

    return result

color = requestColor()

print('Color(%s, %s, %s)' % (color.r, color.g, color.b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call saveCommand() or quitCommand() without calling requestColor(). Its not clear why do you need such a behavior. Much more easier to make class and call these methods as class methods. In example:

```
class ColorHandler():
def __init__(self, color):
       self.color = color
       # do other 

  def requestColor(self, default=Color(0, 0, 0)):
      # set color properties
       self.color = color
       return self.color

  def saveCommand(self):
      return self.requestColor()


  def quitCommand(self):
     return self.requestColor()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all of this; what is the purpose of the color parameter in \_\_init\_\_?